# Have to click submit twice to get it to write to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am having an issue with the following code, it IS working, but the first time you click on the "Update" button (which is the forms 'Submit'), the value in price will revert back to the current value. If you edit the value again and click on "Update" it will write the value to the database (?????)

```cshtml
@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
}

@{
    //Get the layout page and assign the page title
    Layout = "~/SiteManager/_ManagerLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Modify Listing";

    //Get the productId from the query string
    var ProductId = Request.QueryString["ProductId"];

    //Setup validation
    Validation.RequireField("productTitle", "A product title is required.");
    Validation.RequireField("productDescription", "A product description is required.");
    Validation.RequireField("productPrice", "A product price is required.");

    //Open the database
    var db = Database.Open("sg_cart");

    //Build the query to obtain the recordset
    var qrySelectedProduct = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Id = @0";

    //Pass the required parameters and get the currently selectd product
    var selectedProduct = db.QuerySingle(qrySelectedProduct, ProductId);

    if(IsPost)
    {   
        // Validate that request came from the correct form
        AntiForgery.Validate();

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var productTitle = Request.Form["productTitle"];
            var productDescription = Request.Form["productDescription"];
            var productPrice = Request.Form["productPrice"];

            var qryUpdateProduct = "UPDATE Products SET Name = @0, Description = @1, Price = @2 WHERE Id = @3";

            db.Execute(qryUpdateProduct, productTitle, productDescription, productPrice, ProductId);   
        }

    }
}
<h1>@Page.Title for @selectedProduct.Name</h1>
<br />
<div class="container">
    <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked alert alert-success alert-block" action="" method="post">
        @*Generate html key to validate this form *@
        @AntiForgery.GetHtml()`
        @* If one or more validation errors exist, show an error *@
        @Html.ValidationSummary("Update product was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
        <fieldset>
            <legend hidden>Edit @selectedProduct.Name</legend>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td class="content-cell-left">
                <div class="pure-control-group">
                    <label for="productTitle">Product Title</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="productTitle" value="@selectedProduct.Name" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("productTitle")                    
                </div>
                <div class="pure control-group">
                    <label for="productDescription">Product Description</label>
                    <textarea rows="5" cols="100" name="productDescription">@selectedProduct.Description</textarea>
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("productDescription")
                </div>
                <div class="pure-control-group">
                    <label for="productPrice">Product Price</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="productPrice" value="@String.Format("{0:0.00}", selectedProduct.Price)" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("productPrice")
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update" causesValidation="true"/>
                    <input type="button" value="Change Image" onclick='window.location.href="EditProductPicture?ProductId=@selectedProduct.Id"' />
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick='window.location.href="CartManager";' />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="content-cell-right">
               <img src="/Images/Products/@selectedProduct.ImageName" alt="@selectedProduct.ImageName" />
            </td>

            </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>        
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you debug and see what are values of IsPost and IsValid in the function at the first time?

Comment: I got rid of the client side validation and the issue was resolved